# Django creating a route that takes the last part of the URL as parameter for a view?

Tags: django, django-views, routes, get

For example:

I would like:

```
http://localhost:8000/computers/laptops/
```

To return the same as:

```
http://localhost:8000/computers/?c=laptops
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: i think regex would be the way.

Comment: Can you show your views and your urls

Comment: @Irfanwani where and how would you put it? in the urls.py file?

Comment: @bdbd the urls:
path('computers/', views.computer_search_list, name='computer-search-list'),

the view:
def computer_search_list(request):
    cat = request.GET.get('c')
.....

That works so far

Comment: Yeah you can just add that exact url, and write a view that works for `laptop`